# Slide In and Slide Out animation like keyboard in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I want to create a toolbar (initially hidden) with items that can be dragged. If a button is tapped, the toolbar will appear buttom-up (just like the animation of keyboard). I just like to ask how to do it in cocos2d.

Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this code for drawer open and close.

```
-(void)showMyCocos2DDrawer
{
    CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    self.position = ccp(-s.width,0.0f);  //do this in ur init method :)

    CGPoint pos =ccp(0.0f, 0.0f );

    id moveTo = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.5f position:pos];
    id calFun = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(animDone)];
    id seq    = [CCSequence actions:moveTo, calFun, nil];

    [self runAction:seq];
}



-(void)hideCocos2DDrawer
{
    CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    CGPoint pos =ccp(-s.width, 0.0f);

    id moveTo = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.3f position:pos];
    id calFun = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(goBack)];
    id seq    = [CCSequence actions:moveTo, calFun, nil];

    [self runAction:seq];
}

-(void) animDone
{
//write in code here..
}

-(void)goBack
{
//write out code here..
}
```